# Count following groupby on two columns in Pandas doesn't include groups with a zero count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I am grouping by two columns in a Pandas DataFrame, after which I count the size of each group. This grouped DataFrame will then be filtered and the data plotted in a bar chart.

The issue i am having is that if a group has a zero count, it is not shown in the DataFrame and therefore does not appear on the plot. So the plot has missing categories on the x-axis when i would rather them include a category even if there is no bar to display (i.e represent the category as zero, thereby imo making the plot more representative of the data as a whole).

```
# Import the required packages.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set the appearance of plots.
plt.style.use('ggplot')

# Create sample DataFrame.
data = {'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Anne', 'Steve', 'Ricky', 'Jane', 'Beth'], 'Age':[28,34,29,42,15,10,26], 'Voted':[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Bin into age groups and create an Age Group column in the DataFrame.
bins = list(range(0, 60, 10))
df['Age Group'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins, right=False)

# Group data by Age Group and Voted columns. Then perform count using the ID column. Make Age Group the new index.
groups = df.groupby(['Age Group', 'Voted'])
new_df = groups.agg({'ID': 'count'}).rename(columns={'ID':'Count'})    
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_df.set_index('Age Group', inplace=True)
new_df
```

The code above will output this:

```
         Voted  ID
Age Group       
[10, 20)    0   1
[10, 20)    1   1
[20, 30)    0   3
[30, 40)    1   1
[40, 50)    1   1
```

What I'd like is for something like the result below, from which i can filter out just the voted=1 age groups and plot in a chart:

```
         Voted  ID
Age Group
[0, 10)     0   0
[0, 10)     1   0       
[10, 20)    0   1
[10, 20)    1   1
[20, 30)    0   3
[20, 30)    1   0
[30, 40)    0   0
[30, 40)    1   1
[40, 50)    0   0
[40, 50)    1   1
```

I have searched the similar questions/results (most relative below), but i can't seem to get either to work.

[[Pandas groupby for zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003100/pandas-groupby-for-zero-values][1])
[[Pandas Groupby How to Show Zero Counts in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372181/pandas-groupby-how-to-show-zero-counts-in-dataframe][1])

I've also noticed that if i perform the count on just a single column, that zero groups do show up in the DataFrame. Why is this? eg:

```
# Group data by just Age Group column. Then perform count using the ID column.
groups = df.groupby(['Age Group'])
new_df = groups.agg({'ID': 'count'}).rename(columns={'ID':'Count'})
new_df # count displays the zero here for the 0-10 age group.
```

Any help in explaining what is going on here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause `pd.cut` will return categorical data. That is why  you see the different between groupby two column  with only categorical columns

Here is one way to fix the out put  using `reindex`

```
new_df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.unique(pd.cut(np.arange(50), bins, right=False)).tolist(),[0,1]]),fill_value=0)
Out[277]: 
            Count
[0, 10)  0      0
         1      0
[10, 20) 0      1
         1      1
[20, 30) 0      3
         1      0
[30, 40) 0      0
         1      1
[40, 50) 0      0
         1      1
```